# TypeError: Cannot read property 'setMainPage' of undefined in onsen ui, angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, onsen-ui

I am getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'setMainPage' of undefined` error,
with the following `angularjs` `config` and `html`, i am not understading why its giving this error because `setMainPage` is already defined in `onsen-ui` framework, Please help me, Thanks in advance

**Error:**

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'setMainPage' of undefined
at Object.$stateProvider.state.state.onEnter (app.js:28)
at Object.invoke (onsenui_all.min.js:3)
at y.transitionTo.y.transition.M.then.y.transition.y.transition (angular-ui-router.min.js:7)
at processQueue (onsenui_all.min.js:6)
at onsenui_all.min.js:6
at Scope.parent.$get.Scope.$eval (onsenui_all.min.js:8)
at Scope.parent.$get.Scope.$digest (onsenui_all.min.js:8)
at Scope.parent.$get.Scope.$apply (onsenui_all.min.js:8)
at onsenui_all.min.js:2
at Object.invoke (onsenui_all.min.js:3)
```

**app.js (angularjs config)**

```
var app = angular.module('itApp', ['onsen', 'ui.router']);

app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    // By default show Tab 1 - Navigator MasterDetail example
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/main');

    $stateProvider

        // Tab 1 - SlidingMenu example - SlidingMenu init
        .state('sliding', {
            abstract: true,
            // url: '/sliding', // Optional url prefix
            resolve: {
                loaded: function($rootScope) {
                    $rootScope.appTabbar.setActiveTab(1);
                    return $rootScope.appTabbar.loadPage('html/tab2.html');
                }
            }
        })

        // Tab 1 - SlidingMenu example - Landing page
        .state('sliding.main', {
            parent: 'sliding',
            url: '/main',
            onEnter: ['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
                $rootScope.appMenu.setMainPage('map.html', {closeMenu: true});
            }]
        })          
    ;
});
```

**html:**

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html ng-app="itApp">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">     

        <script src="onsen/js/angular/angular.min.js"></script>     
        <script src="onsen/js/onsenui.min.js"></script>
        <script src="onsen/js/angular/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>       

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="onsen/css/onsenui.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="onsen/css/onsen-css-components.css">       

        <script src="jsScripts/app.js"></script>        
        <script src="jsScripts/controllers.js"></script>                    
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="UserController">
        <ons-tabbar  var="appTabbar" animation="none">
            <ons-tab ui-sref="navigator.master">
                <ons-icon icon="ion-home"></ons-icon>
                <span style="font-size: 14px">MasterDetail</span>
            </ons-tab>
            <ons-tab ui-sref="sliding.main">
                <ons-icon icon="ion-star"></ons-icon>
                <span style="font-size: 14px">SlidingMenu</span>
            </ons-tab>
        </ons-tabbar>

        <ons-template id="html/tab1.html">
            <ons-sliding-menu menu-page="menu.jsp" side="left" var="appMenu" type="reveal" max-slide-distance="260px" swipeable="true">
            </ons-sliding-menu>
        </ons-template>

        <ons-template id="html/tab2.html">
            <ons-navigator title="Navigator" var="appNavigator">
            </ons-navigator>
        </ons-template>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The error is not saying that `setMainPage` is not defined, but that `appMenu` is undefined, so you cannot call a method from that variable.

Comment: **because setMainPage is already defined in onsen-ui framework** - obviously this is not the case. might be that `appMenu` is not yet defined in `config` lifecycle. Check where `onsen-ui` registers the `appMenu`. This will probably be in the `run` phase.

Comment: i have already defined  var="appMenu" in <ons-sliding-menu >

Comment: you cannot access variable which will be defined in the `HTML` in the Angular `config` phase.

Comment: might be you are right @Michael, but here in this link [link](http://onsen.io/blog/onsen-ui-router-app/) varialble `var="myMenu"` declared in html are accessing in angular `config` phase.

Comment: what exactly should I see there?? it doesn't say anything about the config phase. it is as it is and you can't change it. In config phase HTML directives has not yet evaluated and therefore are not present. This is simple logic!

Comment: thanks @Michael now i am understanding what problem it has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably trying to access the `appMenu` element before it has been loaded in the DOM. Try wrapping all the `app.config()` code inside an `ons.ready()` function. This function waits for all the DOM elements to be loaded before executing his content.

For example:

```js
var app = angular.module('itApp', ['onsen', 'ui.router']);

ons.ready(function(){
  app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    //content
    
  });
});
```

Comment: Thnks @pavllo For this help.. its really helpful for me